# AngularJS filter based on multi-dimensional JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table in which I am outputting many rows of data.  In that table, I have a column status.

There are about 30 different status values.  There is a dropdown for the column to filter by different statuses, but in the dropdown I only have these statuses: Any, Pending, Inactive, and Placed.

Each of the 4 statuses has many different status values.

If I create a JavaScript object like so:

```
var statuses = {
    'Pending': [
         'Entered',
         'Submitted,
         'Approved'
     ]
};
```

And after Pending there is another array with Inactive which has more statuses.

How can I create a filter in Angular to show the results not where the status from the dropdown is Pending but where the statuses are in the Pending array from above?

Answer (score 0):

You can just access the "Pending" inside the statuses:

```
$scope.statuses = statuses;
```

And inside your `select`:

```
<select>
   <option ng-repeat="options in statuses.Pending">{{options}}</option>
</select>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/6867/)

Comment: The status values are reflected in the table, and I'm trying to have the table show all the rows where the status equals one of the statuses belonging to the selected value from the dropdown.  Is that clearer?

User selects Inactive -> code checks all statuses under Inactive, shows rows where status -> inactive statuses.

Answer (score 0):

In order to populate the table based on the selected element you have to get the value using `ng-model` in the `select` element. And to make sure the `ng-model` variable gets it each time a selection is made you can use `ng-options` to populate all the options from your Statuses. Such as:

```
<select ng-change='loadStats()' ng-model='selectedStatus' ng-options='k as k for (k,v) in stats'>
</select>
```

The `ng-change` is what triggers the event when a selection is made it calls the function from your controller's `$scope`. The string `'k as k for (k,v) in stats'` is simply for handling your `statuses` object and reading it as (Key, Value) pairs then printing the key as Label.

The definition of the controller holds the `loadStats()` and other initializations of `$scope` variables:

```
function Ctrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.stats = statuses;
    $scope.table = tableData;
    $scope.tableShow = $scope.table;
    $scope.selectedStatus = 'Pending';
    $scope.status = $scope.stats[$scope.selectedStatus];
    $scope.loadStats = function() {
        $scope.status = $scope.stats[$scope.selectedStatus];
    };

}
```

After the selection is made, to populate the table you need the filter to be defined. The filter depends on the array of the selected status and all the rows. For populating the table you can use an array of objects. This array can help us filter too. Suppose the table's data is represented like:

```
var tableData = [
{status: 'Entered', value: '1'},
{status: 'Entered', value: '2'},
{status: 'Submitted', value: '3'},
{status: 'Approved', value: '4'},
{status: 'A', value: '1'},
{status: 'B', value: '2'},
{status: 'C', value: '1'},
]
```

Now to populate the table we use the filter defined like:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('filterMyStats',function(){
    return function (table, status) {
        return table.filter(function(row){
            if (status.indexOf(row.status) != -1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        })
    }
});
```

And we apply the filter using the `ng-repeat`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="tr in tableShow | filterMyStats:status">
    <td>{{tr.status}}</td><td>{{tr.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here's a
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tafhim/g7ch4j5v/)